# Retrieve metadata from a database with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, metadata

I'd like to retrieve the metadata from a given database with EntityFramework. I've tried to use this code :

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
var meta = objectContext.GetMetadataWorkspace().GetEntityContainer(objectContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
var sets = meta.BaseEntitySets;
```

But `sets` is empty because the POCOs have to be created first.

I'd like to retrieve the metadata in order to create the POCOs without using the designer tool.